# Updated dataframe column value failed to overwrite in Hive

Tags: apache-spark, hive

Consider hive table `tbl` with column `aid` and `bid`

```
|  aid | bid  |
---------------
|      |  12  |
|  24  |  13  |
|  18  |   3  |
|      |   7  |
---------------
```

requirement is when `aid` is null or empty string, `aid` should be overwritten by value of `bid`

```
|  aid | bid  |
---------------
|  12  |  12  |
|  24  |  13  |
|  18  |   3  |
|   7  |   7  |
---------------
```

code is simple

```
val df01 = spark.sql("select * from db.tbl")
val df02 = df01.withColumn("aid", when(col("aid").isNull || col("aid") <=>  "", col("bid")) otherwise(col("aid")))
```

and when running in `spark-shell`, `df02.show` displayed correct data just like above table

problem is when write the data back to hive

```
df02.write
  .format("orc")
  .mode("Overwrite")
  .option("header", "false")
  .option("orc.compress", "snappy")
  .insertInto(tbl)
```

there is no error but when I validate the data

```
select * from db.tbl where aid is null or aid= '' limit 10;
```

I can still see multiple rows return from the query with aid being null

How to overwrite the data back to hive if previously update column value just like above example?

Comment: Can you verify the length of aid? May be it has length greater than zero?

Comment: Please fix your question, the `val df02 = withColumn("aid", when(col("aid").isNull || col("aid") <=>  "", col("bid")))` doesn't look right... After that, please check `when`'s behavior that  "If `otherwise` is not defined at the end, null is returned for unmatched conditions."

Comment: @Piyush Patel thanks do you mean the length of column header?

Comment: @mazaneicha Thank you I fixed the code, and added otherwise condition, I tested in Spark shell result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

I would try this

```scala
df02.write
  .orc
  .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
  .option("compression", "snappy")
  .insertInto(tbl)
```